# How to fix missing styles when using theme in TextInputLayout

Tags: android, xml

I use the TextInputLayout widget for custom EditText.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:theme="@style/EditTextHint"
        android:id="@+id/panelID"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Engage code here"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

With style :

```
<style name="EditTextHint" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorAccent">#DD4B39</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">#DD4B39</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#545454</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">#545454</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">#545454</item>
    </style>
```

To get some custom EditText. But I found some error 
[image: Error show]

When I ignore the error, and still run my application there is no error, just a warning on the `design panel` in android  studio

What should I add in the style that the error could be disappear?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your parent should be @android:style/TextAppearance instead of TextAppearance.AppCompat

Comment: I try your solution, but still have same error code

Comment: <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">#545454</item>

Comment: add this line of code instead of the last line <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">#545454</item>

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use another nameSpace for attribute `colorControlHighlight`

Try this:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

instead this

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Comment: Still same error....Android Studio automatically add `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`